# Teamed Network card on exchange - outlook not connecting

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, exchange-2010

I have teamed the 4 NIC to a static IP and restarted our Exchange 2010 server running windows 2008 R2.

Now Outlook will not connect to Exchange it is showing Disconnected.

Comment: can you simply ping the ip address?

Comment: Does anything work?  Does OWA work, does HTTP work?

Comment: I can ping the exchange server and I can get into owa

Comment: Was Outlook left running while the Exchange server was restarting?

Comment: and you can rdp to it correct?

Comment: Thank you all for your help I have posted the answer below. My nerves are shot but problem solved :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exchange Services had stopped, which stopped Outlook from connecting. After filling in the static IP details for the teamed network cards, the Gateway was for some reason removed so I added this back in and Exchange sprang to life.